# Converting groups/layers in fabricjs to image

Tags: fabricjs

Im currently looking into fabric.js as well as konva.js and fabric.js seems to have the advantage not to have to implement all selection tools manually; However while in konva.js it is quite obvious how to extract an image "projection" of a layer (as each layer there has at least one canvas on its own), I dont know if difficult it is to convert a group in fabric.js into an image (not svg!). Basically I need some output object which I can convert into a bitmap of certain size for further processing steps.

Thank you for any help :)!

Answer (score 3):

So each object in fabric, including the Groups of object comes with a toDataUrl method.

In this basic basic example i create a fabricJS circle, i do not add it to a canvas, i just exec its own dataURL method.
Before i add a scale factor just to make it bigger.

```js
var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 50, fill: 'blue', stroke: 'red'});
circle.scaleX = 20;
circle.scaleY = 20;
document.getElementById('i').src = circle.toDataURL();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<img id="i" />
```

Comment: How can we make a transparent image of a particular object with its shadow property and stroke property? It got Cut currently.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I'm a bit late to the party but, how could I go about generating canvas image FROM serialized canvas OR parsed canvas ? I need to create multiple images from multiple canvases (serialized or parsed matters not really). Do I need to initialize the canvas with 'new' in order to convert canvas to image ?  I wanna avoid that initialization because I may need to print thousands of images (canvas images)

Answer (score 3):

You can use fabric's built-in `cloneAsImage` function:

```js
group.cloneAsImage(image => {
    image.set({...do settings});

    canvas.add(image);
});
```

see more here: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#cloneAsImage